# Use action button to advance to next image with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have several JPGs in a folder and I want to display an image and allow a user to click a button and a different image in that folder will be displayed. So far I have

```
library(shiny)

dir <- "dir/to/images/www/"
img_files <- list.files(dir)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    img(src = sample(img_files,1),height = 500),
    actionButton("next_btn", label = "Next")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    observeEvent(input$next_btn, {
        img(src = sample(img_files,1),height=500)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This displays an image from the folder but the next button has no effect. How can I make it so that a different random image will be displayed when the next button is pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `renderImage()` on the server side and put the `input$next_btn` in a `set.seed()`.

```r
library(shiny)

dir <- "dir/to/images/www/"
img_files <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    
    actionButton("next_btn", label = "Next"),
    plotOutput("plot", height=500)
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderImage({
    
    set.seed(input$next_btn)
    list(src = sample(img_files, 1))
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```